# Error thrown when attempting to use Vowpal Wabbit option --link=logistic

Tags: vowpalwabbit

Until recently the following sequence of commands were working just fine:

```
vw -d ${traindata} --cache_file ${cachefile} -f ${modelname} --passes ${npasses} --loss_function logistic -l ${lrate} 
vw -d ${testdata} -t -i ${modelname} --link=logistic -p ${preds}
```

Now when I run this the following error gets thrown at the prediction step:

```
vw: unrecognised option '--link=logistic'
```

Do I need to link something to get vw to recognize this option? Until just today this worked fine by default. The only change I have made is to update my ~/.bashrc profile with new PATH exports. Previously I had been using my bash profile to link to functions in the `/utils` folder.

Cheers,

Aaron

**UPDATE**

Meant to mention that I also recently updated to VW version 8.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also experienced that error when attempting to use `--link=logistic`. I had installed Vowpal Wabbit via synaptic and was on VW version 7.3 as a result. By downloading and compiling VW directly from the official repo, I ended up on VW version 8.2.0, and I'm able to successfully execute my vw command with `--link=logistic`.